# fail to train a model using tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I tried to use `tf.function` to decorate the gradient update function as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, activations, losses
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Progbar

# generate data
nb_doc = 100
doc_features = np.random.random((nb_doc, 10))
doc_scores = np.random.randint(2, size=nb_doc).astype(np.float32)

class simple_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense = [layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu), layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)]
        self.score = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        dense_a = self.dense[0](inputs)
        for dense in self.dense[1:]:
            dense_a = dense(dense_a)
        y = self.score(dense_a)
        return y
    
    def build_graph(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10))
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=self.call(x))
        
batch_size = 1
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((doc_features, doc_scores)).shuffle(nb_doc).batch(batch_size)

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

@tf.function
def apply_gradient(optimizer, model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss_value = loss_object(y, y_pred)
    
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
    
    return y_pred, loss_value


def train_data_for_one_epoch(optimizer, model):
    losses = []
    pb_i = Progbar(np.ceil(nb_doc // batch_size), stateful_metrics=['loss'])
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train):
        y_pred, loss_value = apply_gradient(optimizer, model, x, y)
        losses.append(loss_value)

        pb_i.update(step+1, values=[('loss', loss_value)], finalize=False)
    pb_i.update(step+1, values=[('loss', np.mean(losses))], finalize=True)
    return losses
```

I can train a model successfully the first time I call the code below.
But it fail when I train to train another model using the **same code**, with error message `ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.`

```
# this succeed
epochs = 5
_model = simple_model()
loss_history = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch %d/%d'%(epoch+1, epochs))
    losses_train = train_data_for_one_epoch(optimizer, _model)
    loss_history.append(np.mean(losses_train))

# this fail
epochs = 5
_model_2 = simple_model()
loss_history = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch %d/%d'%(epoch+1, epochs))
    losses_train = train_data_for_one_epoch(optimizer, _model_2)
    loss_history.append(np.mean(losses_train))
```

Comment: There must be something different between the two models, but without the full error and the code that causes the error, it is hard to make a diagnostic.

Comment: I think you'll need to reinitialize the optimizer after training the first model.

Comment: these are the full code already, you could reproduce the issue with the code above. FYI, im using TF v2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be a known issue as indicated here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27120)

And the work around is

```
# removed @tf.function decorator
def apply_gradient(optimizer, loss_object, model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss_value = loss_object(y, y_pred)
    
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
    
    return y_pred, loss_value


def train_data_for_one_epoch(optimizer, loss_object, model):
    losses = []
    
    # added tf.function here
    apply_grads =tf.function(apply_gradient)
    
    pb_i = Progbar(np.ceil(nb_doc // batch_size), stateful_metrics=['loss'])
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train):
        y_pred, loss_value = apply_grads(optimizer, loss_object, model, x, y)
        losses.append(loss_value)

        pb_i.update(step+1, values=[('loss', loss_value)], finalize=False)
    pb_i.update(step+1, values=[('loss', np.mean(losses))], finalize=True)
    return losses
```

Then the two models could train without error.